# Is there a TCL cmd to grep a particular line and awk a particular word

Tags: tcl

Lets say below is something i've stored in a config variable in tcl.

```
#set config "configuration {
test_config {
    address 1.2.3.4:https
}
}"
```

Using tcl cmd, either grep or awk or string cmds, how do i take out "1.2.3.4:https" into a variable.

So when i use do something like below,

```
#puts $output
1.2.3.4:https
```

I know how it can be done in simple bash though

```
#echo $config | grep address | awk '{print $2}'
#1.2.3.4:https
```

Can someone please help in tcl. I tried to explore string functions, but they are not giving my required output and I'm learning about regexp now.

Comment: Your $config is a proper dict, so maybe you just want `dict get $config configuration test_config address`. That will be more robust than simply looking for a line containing "address".

Comment: Thank you Schelte, this $config keeps changing, so the strings Inside this variable changes, example - instead of test_config it can be dev_config also. Same goes for configuration, it can be dev configuration as its name.

Comment: That looks like an nginx configuration; those aren't guaranteed to be proper Tcl lists.

Comment: That's right. Is there way to search for next string after the match of address word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `regexp` command, especially with the `-line` option. The trick here is to use `\s*` (or `\s+`) to match spaces and `\S+` to match non-spaces.

```
if {[regexp -line {^\s*address\s+(\S+)} $config -> address]} {
    puts "The address is $address"
}
```

If there are multiple `address` lines, you might instead do:

```
foreach {-> address} [regexp -inline -all -line {^\s*address\s+(\S+)} $config] {
    puts "The address is $address"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Donal, really appreciate it. It works

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure Donal's suggestion is the more efficient: here's a procedural way to do it:

```
foreach line [split $config \n] {
    lassign [regexp -inline -all {\S+} $line] first second
    if {$first eq "address"} {
        set output $second
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Glenn, I'll give it a try. I could understand this logic.